# Swift3 - cannot locate UISegmentedControl programmatically

Tags: swift3, uisegmentedcontrol, cgrect

I have a button which I can locate easily with this code:

```
let btnRewind = UIButton(
    frame:CGRect(
        x:(UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height/2 - 4*UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height/30),
        y:(UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width/2 - UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height/30),
        width:(UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height/15),
        height:(UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height/15)
    )
)
```

But same code does not work for my UISegmentedControl. That goes x:0 y:0. What am I missing :/

```
var sgmSpeed = UISegmentedControl(
    frame:CGRect(
        x:(UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height/2 - UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height/30),
        y:(UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width/2 - UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height/30),
        width:(UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height/15),
        height:(UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width/15)

    )
)
```

Comment: Try using the `initWithItems` constructor.  Docs say, "automatically sized to fit its content".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one is worked, thanks to Philip Mills

```
sgmSpeed.frame = CGRect.init(x:(UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height/2 - UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height/6),
                                 y:(UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width/2 + UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height/15),
                                 width:(UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height/3),
                                 height:(UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width/15))
```